# Equation of parabola using axis and tangent at vertex

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Let $L=ax+by+c=0$ be the axis of a parabola, and the tangent at vertex be $M=bx-ay+d=0$

If $L^2=4pM$ is the equation of that parabola whose length of latus rectum is $4p$, then $a^2+b^2$ must be equal to $1$. But how does this condition come?

Comment: Your equation is a parabola, but if you want metric properties like the length of the latus rectum, $p=2f,$ then it’s important to keep lengths. Note that for axis $-x=0$ and tangent at vertex $y=0$ then the equation is $x^2=4fy,$ and certainly $a^2+b^2=(-1)^2+0^2=1.$ Keeping unit vectors along axis and tangent at vertex just assures that lengths also are kept, but are you sure $a=f$?

Comment: I forgot that I had used "a" before. Edited*

Answer (score 1):

To understand this condition, we must understand a particular definition of the parabola.

Using your notation, let 2 perpendicular lines be

$ L = ax+by+c=0$

$M = bx-ay+d=0$

Then the locus of the point $(h,k)$ such that the square of its perpendicular distance from $L$ is proportional to its perpendicular distance from $M$ with a proportionality constant which is the length of the latus rectum, say $4p$.

Mathematically, it can be represented as follows:-

$$
\left( \frac {ah+bk+c}{\sqrt {a^2 +b^2}} \right)^2 = 4p \left( \frac {bh-ak+d}{\sqrt {a^2 +b^2}} \right)
$$

Which upon on substitution and cancellation yields

$$
\frac{L^2}{\sqrt {a^2 +b^2}}= 4pM
$$

This works for any parabola. Now applying your condition and comparing the equations, we can conclude that $\sqrt {a^2 +b^2} = 1$ and $ a^2 +b^2 = 1$